# Using while statement with WebDriverWait and expected_conditions

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to deal with a web with AJAX and jquery. I want to scroll down until reach certain section, so I did some approaches with wait and EC, without sucess, like this:

```
 scroll_bottom = """$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()},'fast');"""
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 # from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 # wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
 while EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"STOP_HERE")):
     driver.execute_script(scroll_bottom)
```

Is there any way to deal with wait and EC, in order to do something until some element is visible and/or clickable?

EDIT:

I did some dirty tricks with javascript, but definitely is not the pythonic way to reach my goal.

```
def scroll_b():
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    driver.execute_script(load_jquery)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    js = """return document.getElementById("STOP_HERE")"""
    selector = driver.execute_script(js)
    while not  selector :
        driver.execute_script(scroll_bottom)
        time.sleep(1)
        selector = driver.execute_script(js)
    print("END OF SCROLL")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not how the built in Expected Conditions are intended to work. Generally speaking, once you activate them, they block until whatever condition returns True.

I think what you want is a custom expected condition. This is untested:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

scroll_bottom = """$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()},'fast');"""

def scroll_wait(driver):
    # See if your element is present
    # Use the plural 'elements' to prevent throwing an exception
    # if the element is not yet present
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_id("STOP_HERE")

    # Now use a conditional to control the Wait
    if elem and elem[0].is_enabled and elem[0].is_displayed:
        # Returning True (or something that is truthy, like a non-empty list)
        # will cause the selenium Wait to exit
        return elem[0]
    else:
        # Scroll down more
        driver.execute_script(scroll_bottom)

        # Returning False will cause the Wait to wait and then retry
        return False

# Now use your custom expected condition with a Wait
TIMEOUT = 30  # 30 second timeout
WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT, poll_frequency=0.25).until(scroll_wait)
```

What's nice about this approach is that it will throw an exception after 30 seconds (or whatever you set TIMEOUT to).

Comment: That's a clever solution, way better than mine. It's a pity how great webdriver is, and how it lacks of a statement-friendly function to, well, "just expect a condition".
Thanks!.